# Loop through teams and use sub routine

Tags: vba, loops, range, subroutine

I have to run a loop through a range a4:a13 on a specific sheet which are team names a-h. When this loop runs through the team names i need it to run my other code which is generic for only team A at the moment. How do i use a loop and sub routine to make this automated so its runs for all teams without having to duplicate the code

so far i have

```
Sub Looproutine()

Dim i As Integer

Dim TeamName As String

TeamName = Sheets("Parametres")
("A"&(str(i)).value

For i = 4 To 13

Call tidydata(Team(i))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you could go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Looproutine()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Parametres").Range("A4:A13") '<~~ loop through every cell of your relevant range

        tidydata cell.Value '<~~ call "tidydata()" passing it the current cell value

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Do i need to define what tidydata is first?

Comment: well, since you already had that `Call tidydata(Team(i))` I assumed you already have some `Sub tidydata(teamName as String)  ... (code to handle data  given the team name)... End Sub` in your project!

Comment: Yeah, i wasnt too sure where to put it but that all makes sense now, cheers!

Comment: glad to be of help. If I fulfilled your question then please mark answer as accepted. thank you